# Removing first View and Creating a second View (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am working on the following feature: When a user clicks on a photo on the page, a modal `modalView` appears with more details of that item. In `modalView`, the user can click on the photo of another item, which will close the first modal window `modalView` and open a new modal window `modalView` containing full details of this next item. The opening and closing of `modalView`s are handled by the router functions.

*(the user may experience a flicker, but thats another problem)*

**Problem:** When the user clicks on the photo of another item within `modalView`, `showModal()` will cause the current `modalView` to close and the URL updates to that of the next item `/product/1234`, but the new `modalView` does not appear! Using `console.log()` to debug, I found that the first `modalView` closes, the 2nd `modalView` opens then closes!

What has happened, and how can this be fixed?

**Router**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {,
        'product/:id': 'showModal'
    },


    showModal: function(id) {
        // Close any existing ModalView
        if(app.modalView) {
            app.modalView.closeModal();
            console.log('closing');
        }

        // Create new ModalView
        app.modalView = new ModalView({ model: new Product({id:id}) });
        console.log('creating new');
    }

});

app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/'
});
```

**View**

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    events: {
        'click .more_photo': 'showModal',
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // Update Model with Full details
        var self = this;
        this.model.fetch({
            data: {post_id: self.model.get('id')},
            processData: true,
            success: function() {
                self.render();
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).show().append( this.template( this.model.toJSON( this.model ) ) );
    },

    closeModal: function() {
        // Restore scrollbars
        $(this.el).css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');

        // Close modal and remove contents
        $(this.el).fadeOut();
        $(this.el).empty();
    },

    showModal: function() {
        // Update URL & Trigger Router function `showModal`
        app.navigate('/product/' + this.model.get('id'), {trigger:true});
    }
});
```

**Console.log Output**

```
creating new
               <----clicks on another photo
closing
creating new
```

Comment: IS the route firing twice or just the `closeModal` method? Anyway instead of closing the modal and reopening have you tried just swapping the views model (something like `app.modelView.model = new Product({id:id}); app.ModelView.model.fetch();`)

Comment: `closeModal` method seems to be fired twice, once to close the first view, and once after the second view has been created, closing this second view. I will look into your suggestion :)

Comment: I tried recreating a simplified version of your example and the `closeModal` method was only (correctly) firing once.

Comment: I've successfully used the first method you've suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided I'm not sure why your `closeModal` method might be firing twice, I've created a simplified version off of your code and the method was only called once each time (of course I improvised a bit so maybe that had something to do with it).

As an alternative to closing your and reopening your modal view  each time you might want to try just swapping the model.

For  example

```
 showModal: function(id) {

        if(app.modalView) {
            app.modalView.model = new Product({id:id});
            app.modalView.model.fetch();
        } else {
           app.modalView = new ModalView({ model: new Product({id:id}) });
        }
    }
```